# Symfony how to have multiple signed in users

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am developing and application in symfony, with a pulic access where users logs in with a login form and an admin section with another login form and another user provider.

I've created a LoginFormAuthenticator for each area, and two firewalls to select the correct authenticator in each area. This is my security.yaml:

security:
providers:
admin_provider:
entity:
class: App\Entity\AdminUser
property: email
web_provider:
entity:
class: App\Entity\User
property: email

```
firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern: '^/admin'
        anonymous: true
        provider: admin_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: /admin/logout
            target: /
    main:
        anonymous: true
        provider: web_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: /logout
```

Now I am adding an /api to the project, and both users should be able to access, managing the access rights diferently if the user is a public user or is an admin user.

When developing a controller in the /api area, I am unable to get the user when logged via the admin.

The question is, How in /api I can get the AdminUser if it is logged in or the User (in this order) when accessing $this->getuser() or $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted() ?

I've tried to add the App\Security\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator in main firewall and add a chain_provider in main.provider. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewalls should share a "common context", for being able to access the same connected users. I think that wording comes from Symfony 2, where the `SecurityContext` was the service storing the user & authorization.

You need to modify slightly your configuration, and then `$this->getUser()` and `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted()` will return/use the same User object for both firewalls.

```
firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern: '^/admin'
        context: my_app_context
        anonymous: true
        # ...
    main:
        anonymous: true
        context: my_app_context
        # ...
```

No need for a common provider or a custom guard. Though it may be easier to have the same `User` class everywhere, or at least common role for clarity.

Comment: Hi @romaricdrigon, the problem is that there are two entities for each User at each firewall, a user can login in admin and login in public site with different users. This approach makes the same entity being used at both sections. If there is possible to keep the two entities I prefer it. If not I would try to join the entities in a single entity.

Comment: It is challenging to have Security working with an "AdminUser" if you are connected as an "User", and vice-versa. And I suspect having code handling one user or the other will be tricky. I would try to set up a base entity, common to the 2 firewalls, and eventually to have AdminUser / User extend it for some extra optional) information.

Comment: Finally I've decided to use your approach, with a single entity shared between firewalls, maintaining the firewalls for the two different login forms (althought not necessary, just for design purpose) and maanaging access control via roles. Thanks